# Very slow debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I try to debug Jonas webapp under Eclipse. Unfortunately when I connect to the remote application everything works terriblly slow (also after killing all java applications and restarting the PC). I use also JRebel. What might be the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: We need more details. What have you tried so far? How far is the remote application latency/bandwidth-wise? Does your computer swap? Need more input.

Comment: Me too i use jrebel. i wonder if that is related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using the Java Monitoring and Management Console. This may help show where the "slowness" is. Keep an eye on the garbage collector and how much time the JVM is spending dowing garbage collection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Answer (score 1):

I changed values of `-XX:MaxPermSize`, `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters in `eclipse.ini` and it helped.

Comment: Hmm that didn't help me at all

Answer (score 0):

Recently i was having extreme slow performance debug, both in eclipse and visual studio code.

In my case, the problem was with ***lombok*** configuration in ***JPA*** entities.

I changed the **@*Data*** anottation to ***@Getters*** and ***@Setters***.

Looks like **hashCode**() and **equals**() implementantion of **lombok** was in conflict with JPA.